# Security to the Party [Part 15]

Tags: password

Wow. It's all about spaghetti with you folks huh. Well plot twist! He has a new get-rich recipe for pie!

As usual you hide and listen the the passwords, this time to you decide to make a chart:

> "10" -> "5"
>   "6" -> "3"

At this point your friend has had enough. He's been taken by security, trampled by elephants. He's tired of you being the one to get in. He tells you this will be the last time he goes for that recipe! He walks up to security and they give him the number "2" he whispers the number in their ear so you can't hear it and he gets in. Traitor!

It seems you arrived late and only got to hear 2 guests! So you walk up anyway and get the number "14" what's your response?

Comment: I bet no one's gonna waste their time posting an answer with `7`, and that ends up being the correct answer...

Comment: @Martin Usually it'd be the friend that makes the dumb answer XD

Comment: It doesn't matter what you answer. Your friend whispered, "If you let me in, I'll point out the guy who keeps stealing the spaghetti recipes."

Comment: @Roger Funny haha +1

Comment: Need more than the two data points provided. Otherwise it could be any number of things.

Comment: @A E Another response will be a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realizing that my friend is cluing me in on the fact that the pattern is not the obvious one I confidently answer:

> 1

Because of course, my friend answered:

> 1 as well!

Had he not whispered it,

> It would have confirmed the wrong notion that the answer is to divide by 2.

As a side note, I originally took some time to compose [my own party question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4088/the-security-to-the-party-16) and didn't see this one until I was checking to see what the latest number was before setting the number on mine. Since my question has now been answered, I will lay out how I arrived at this number:

> The new recipe is one for "Pie".
>
>  The numbers index digits in Pi with a modulo added in to stop at the 5th digit.
>
> ```
> 1->3,  2->1,  3->4,  4->1,  5->5
> 6->3,  7->1,  8->4,  9->1,  10->5
> 11->3, 12->1, 13->4, 14->1, 15->5
> ```
>
> etc.

Comment: Interesting answer, but no, this is not the pattern that the host has in mind this time.

Comment: I don't understand.  If this is not the correct answer, then why was it accepted?

Answer (score 9):

The answer is 7.

Based on all the previous puzzles in this series, your friend always goes for the obvious solution.  The obvious solution based on the 2 clues here is to take half of what the security guy tells you.  This time your friend got in, so the obvious solution must be the correct one.  So if they say "14" to you, then you should reply with "7".

Comment: Well, I've only made 1 previous question in the series. Also, another recurring pattern is that it's never the obvious answer. This is not the answer, but good try.

Comment: @warspyking Someone had to post it!

Comment: True lol. What is it WAS correct?

Comment: @pacoverflow I have very bad news for you (and for us all): http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/puzzling-se-where-we-hate-fun-its-time-to-disallow-challenge-questions - Visit this please: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19142/another-home-for-challenges

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> 0

And incidentally, my friend's number was

> 1

You see, the key is that

> You need to add a digit to make the entire number divisible by 7.
>  105 = 15 x 7
>  63 = 9 x 7
>  21 = 3 x 7 (28 would've worked as well)
>  140 = 20 x 7 (and 147 would've worked too)

Answer (score 1):

Disappointed that my previous answer did not work, I get in my time machine and go back to the point right before I made my original answer, and instead I try:

> 5

Because my friend answered:

> 3

The reason being:

> The host had some sort of thing with 5 and 3 whereby a two digit number was answered with 5 and a one-digit number was answered with 3.

Comment: Note quite. But um, A+ for effort.